# want to login customer via phone number in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

I want to login customer via phone number in magento 2.2.2. I had seen earlier questions about this but answer is not found. Anyone please help me to achieve this.

**this is my LoginPost .php**

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Customer\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
*/
class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
 */
protected $customerAccountManagement;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator
 */
protected $formKeyValidator;

/**
 * @var AccountRedirect
 */
protected $accountRedirect;

/**
 * @var Session
 */
protected $session;

/**
 * @var ScopeConfigInterface
 */
private $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
 */
private $cookieMetadataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
 */
private $cookieMetadataManager;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Session $customerSession
 * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
 * @param CustomerUrl $customerHelperData
 * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
 * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
    AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
    CustomerUrl $customerHelperData,
    Validator $formKeyValidator,
    AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
) {
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
    $this->customerUrl = $customerHelperData;
    $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
    $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Get scope config
 *
 * @return ScopeConfigInterface
 * @deprecated 100.0.10
 */
private function getScopeConfig()
{
    if (!($this->scopeConfig instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface)) {
        return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class
        );
    } else {
        return $this->scopeConfig;
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieve cookie manager
 *
 * @deprecated 100.1.0
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
 */
private function getCookieManager()
{
    if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
        $this->cookieMetadataManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::class
        );
    }
    return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
}

/**
 * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
 *
 * @deprecated 100.1.0
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
 */
private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
{
    if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::class
        );
    }
    return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
}

/**
 * Login post action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $this->session->regenerateId();
                if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                    $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                    $metadata->setPath('/');
                    $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
                }
                $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
                    $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                    // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
                    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
                    return $resultRedirect;
                }
            } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                $message = __(
                    'This account is not confirmed. <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                    $value
                );
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                $message = __(
                    'You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.'
                );
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                $message = __('You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.');
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // PA DSS violation: throwing or logging an exception here can disclose customer password
                $this->messageManager->addError(
                    __('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.')
                );
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
        }
    }

    return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
}
```

}

Comment: Before , answering this question, have some query,? Is  the phone is an customer  custom attribute or it customer address attribute?

Comment: phone is a customer address attribute

Comment: please give me a  answer to my question..  I'm new to magento

Comment: What would your input for login customer phone no and password?

Comment: yes phone number and password

Comment: Do you want to try the extension? https://magecomp.com/magento-2-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 6):

As you want to **logged in a customer** with there default billing address telephone and its password.

So, you have to create a custom module where you have check

> - Your entered phone number exists in the system,
> - If this phone number exits then, Get Email id of that user from this    phone number
> - After that you using fetch email and password, you can log in easily and follow rest of Magento default logic.

To achieve it, you **should  REWRITE of  the Action class**
`Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost` **fully**.

---

First, create a ***model class where we will check the phone number exists in the system and get the email from that phone number no***.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by Amit Bera.
 * User: Amit Kumar Bera
 * Email: dev.amitbera@gmail.com
 * Date: 10-05-2018
 * Time: 22:44
 */

namespace {Vendorname}\{ModuleName}\Model;


class LoginByTelephone
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $customerCollecctionFactory;

    /**
     * LoginByTelephone constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollecctionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollecctionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->customerCollecctionFactory = $customerCollecctionFactory;
    }

    public function authenticateByTelephone($telephone, $password)
    {
        $collection = $this->customerCollecctionFactory->create();
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'billing_telephone',
            'customer_address/telephone',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        )
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['email', 'billing_telephone','entity_id'])
            ->setPageSize(1)
            ->setCurPage(1)   ;
        if($collection->count() >= 1 ){
            return $collection->getFirstItem()->getData('email');
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

### REWRITE CLASS

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by Amit Bera.
 * User: Amit Kumar Bera
 * Email: dev.amitbera@gmail.com
 * Date: 10-05-2018
 * Time: 22:56
 */

namespace {Vendorname}\{ModuleName}\Rewrite\Customer;


use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator
     */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var AccountRedirect
     */
    protected $accountRedirect;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private $cookieMetadataManager;
    /**
     * @var \StackExchange\Works\Model\LoginByTelephone
     */
    protected $loginByTelephone;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param CustomerUrl $customerHelperData
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        CustomerUrl $customerHelperData,
        Validator $formKeyValidator,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
        \StackExchange\Works\Model\LoginByTelephone $loginByTelephone
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->customerUrl = $customerHelperData;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
        $this->loginByTelephone = $loginByTelephone;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    /**
     * Get scope config
     *
     * @return ScopeConfigInterface
     * @deprecated 100.0.10
     */
    private function getScopeConfig()
    {
        if (!($this->scopeConfig instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface)) {
            return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class
            );
        } else {
            return $this->scopeConfig;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie manager
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private function getCookieManager()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
            $this->cookieMetadataManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
            $this->cookieMetadataFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Login post action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $telePhone = $login['username'];
                    $emailId = $this->loginByTelephone->authenticateByTelephone($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    // If email id does exits then throw error
                    if(!$emailId)
                    {
                        $message = __(
                            'Invalid  is Telephone nO.'
                        );
                        $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                        $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                        return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
                    }
                    $login['username'] =  $emailId;

                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                    if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                        $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                        $metadata->setPath('/');
                        $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
                    }
                    $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                    if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
                        $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                        // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
                        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
                        return $resultRedirect;
                    }
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                        'This account is not confirmed. <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                        $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                   //$this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                    $this->session->setUsername($telePhone);
                } catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                    $message = __(
                        'You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.'
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    //$this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                    $this->session->setUsername($telePhone);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    $message = __('You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    //$this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                    $this->session->setUsername($telePhone);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // PA DSS violation: throwing or logging an exception here can disclose customer password
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        __('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.')
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }

        return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
    }
}
```

Comment: can i replace the full loginpost.php to your code.?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a plugin (instead of rewriting LoginPostClass)

/etc/di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement">
    <plugin name="stackexchange_works_plugin_accountmanagement_plugin"
            type="StackExchange\Works\Plugin\AccountManagementPlugin"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Plugin code, use Amit's LoginByTelephoneClass to get customer mail

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Works\Plugin;
class AccountManagementPlugin
{
 /**
 * @var \StackExchange\Works\Model\LoginByTelephone
 */
protected $loginByTelephone;

  /**
 * AccountManagementPlugin constructor.
 * @param \StackExchange\Works\Model\LoginByTelephone $loginByTelephone
 */
public function __construct(
    \StackExchange\Works\Model\LoginByTelephone $loginByTelephone
)
{
    $this->loginByTelephone = $loginByTelephone;
}

/**
 * Fetch customer mail by telephone
 * @param $subject
 * @param $username
 * @param $password
 * @return array
 */
public function beforeAuthenticate($subject, $username, $password)
{
        if ($email = $this->loginByTelephone->authenticateByTelephone($username)) {
            $username = $email;
        }

    return [$username, $password];
}
}
```

Comment: how can use this.?  please specify with the file name and format. i'm new to magento

Comment: can you give me a full plugin, I don't known how to use this.. :(

Comment: At first you have to create a new module, see: https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/ after that include /etc/di.xml in your module's folder, add my Plugin code as "AccountManagementPlugin.php" to a new directory "Plugin" inside your module directory, add Amit's LoginByTelephone class to a new directory called Model in your module directory.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you can take a look

Place plugin in your file etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">
    <plugin name="customCustomerRepositoryPlugin" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepositoryPlugin" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

The main file put around in method get

```
public function aroundGet(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $email,
    $websiteId = null
) {
    //Main logic here
    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
    if ($websiteId === null) {
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    }

    $resource = $customer->getResource();
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $bind = ['mobilenumber' => $email];
    //You will need filter email here but with your mobilenumber input
}
```

Better avoid rewrite class if possible